# Sent BTC from Coinbase, blockchain explorer says Confirmed. Recipient didn't receive it. How can I confirm?

Tags: transactions, coinbase.com

On Thursday evening July 21 @ 23:42 PM CT I transferred around $501.22 from Coinbase to an external wallet.

Per Coinbase, they sent it out to the BlockChain, it was confirmed by the BlockChain.
I noticed it has 235 confirmations - Not sure if this is how it works.

The recipient insists they didn't receive the funds.

A week earlier, on July 14, I sent BTC from Coinbase to the same Dest address and it was received within 20 min.

Would anyone be willing to look at the hash below for both transactions and help me to understand how to read it if everything seems legit?

!! Destination BTC wallet address for both transactions:
bc1q7gedlrgmvgw6xfzam9jj2fl4lde3heeqnd23zm

!! July-21 hash
46ecef0a25568bcd2fa28d2ef4ee3d8320b21e7a5305f3340982528fc597ae7c

!! July-21 - None working transaction:
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/46ecef0a25568bcd2fa28d2ef4ee3d8320b21e7a5305f3340982528fc597ae7c

!! July-14 - working transaction:
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/20b92f07301d9bd3ae713ace94611a0d5c47feb923cf62009a367e351d50cf4f

Much appreciate it folks!!

Answer (score 1):

Both the July 21st and July 14th transaction went through, and the coins were received at bc1q7gedlrgmvgw6xfzam9jj2fl4lde3heeqnd23zm. In fact, in both cases, the coins were spent by the recipient and transacted further.

If the recipient claims they haven't received it, they're either lying or incompetent.

Comment: I had no doubt they received it. Thanks for checking for me.